# rails, has_one, build_#{association}, accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

i am trying to develop a wiki with version history.

my plan is: each time i edit a wiki content, it should get saved as a new one.

for now, i have two models, Wiki, and WikiContent, and following code inside them:

```
class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :wiki_contents 

  has_one :current_wiki, :class_name => "WikiContent"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :current_wiki

  has_one :new_content, :class_name => "WikiContent"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :new_content

end
class WikiContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :wiki
end
```

Wiki model has a field current_id, to know which content is the current one.

in Wiki controller i run

```
def new
  @wiki.build_current_wiki
end
def create
  @wiki=Wiki.new(params[:wiki])
  @wiki.save
  @wiki.current_id=@wiki.current_wiki.id
end
```

But whenever i try to run:

```
def edit
  @wiki.build_new_content
end
```

it assigns NULL to current_wiki.wiki_id.

how can i fix that?
or is there another way to get this to work?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but have you taken a look at vestal_versions (http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) ? It manages the revisions for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may have an easier time if you re-design your models a bit.

```
class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions 

  has_one :latest_revision, :class_name => "Revision", :order => 'updated_at desc', :limit => 1
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :revisions
end

class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :wiki
end


# new Wiki page, first revision
def new
  @wiki = Wiki.new
  @revision = @wiki.revisions.build
end

def create
  @wiki=Wiki.new(params[:wiki])
  @wiki.save
end

# adding a Revision to a Wiki page
def edit
  @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
  @revision = @wiki.revisions.build # creating a new revision on edit
end

def update
  @wiki=Wiki.new(params[:wiki])
  @wiki.save
end

def show
  @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
  @revision = @wiki.latest_revision
end
```

A Wiki has many revisions, but only has one latest revision. Now you don't have to manage `current_id`, since the `latest_revision` association will take care of that for you.

Comment: thanks, shown code is not working, as 'build' syntax for has_many is bit different than for has_one (f.ex.@wiki.build_revision has to be @wiki.revisions.build), but the idea to switch to has_many and use "updated_at desc' moved me few steps forward. i'll keep the current_id though, it makes some queries lighter.